# How to design UI Model when using Aggregate with ID reference only to another Aggregate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I've read Vaughn's(author of Red Book) 3 part series of Effective Aggregate Design [here](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)

Given this code:

```
public class Transaction
{
            public Guid Id { get; private set; }
            public int Number { get; private set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
            public Guid ClientId { get; private set; } // other aggregate reference by ID only
            public Guid BranchId { get; private set; } // other aggregate reference by ID only
            public ICollection<TransactionItem> LineItems { get; private set; }
}
```

Now in the UI, if I want to display also the `Branch.Name` and the `Client.FullName` & `Client.Company.Name`

Should I create flat ViewModel?

```
public class ViewModel
{
     // other transaction properties

     public string ClientName {get;set;}
     public string ClientCompanyName {get;set;}
     public string BranchName {get;set;}
}
```

or ViewModel with complex type?

```
public class ViewModel
{
     // other transaction properties

     public ClientDto { get; set; } // companyName and other details inside
     public string BranchName {get;set;}
}
```

or is there any better way of doing it?
As much as possible I want to write less code but still keeping my Domain Model clean.

Right now Im writing raw sql (database views) and mapping the result to ViewModel, sometimes Im mapping to database view and create mapping in order for Entity Framework to materialize the result to viewmodel.

I also need to give alias to the fields being returned by my views in order to avoid name clash.

But neither feels right because of the amount of code

Does using database/raw sql is the way to go?

Can AutoMapper help me with this?

If you can share how you're doing it, Im also interested to see your code.

Comment: If it's different tables it's cleaner to create separate ViewModels for your Cient and Branch and have fields in your main ViewModel. If we are talking about DDD it doesn't metter how your ViewModel looks like you just should map it right way to your domain entities.

Answer (score 2):

> "Does using database/raw sql is the way to go?"

That would refer to an architecture called CQRS employed by many today which is based on the premise that commands and queries are different problems that should be solved by different solutions. A single unified model will often have to be streched both ways and will end up being less maintainable, focused and performant than having two models.

The domain model is optimized for processing commands so it's normal that trying to query it is painful. You often end up having to call upon many repositories just to construct a moderately complex view-model.

However, you will often read that CQRS is bound to Event Sourcing and having a Command Bus, a different read database updated through projections and having to process commands asynchronously. If you are building a system that is highly concurrent then you may benefit all these patterns, but most systems will never need that and using these techniques will introduce accidental complexity. Here's an interesting article about [CQRS Myths](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/22/busting-some-cqrs-myths/).

If you are using a RDBMS then I suggest that you simply bypass the domain model for queries, but not have a seperate read database.

Also, regarding your flat-vs-unflattened view-model question I would opt for the representation that is most practical for consumers. However, I favor an unflattened structure because it allows you to create meaningful wholes (group highly cohesive data). It may also be easier to construct more complex view-models from existing view-models by composing them together.

Comment: Do ViewModels maps to View 1:1? Lets say I have two views which needs ClientViewModel and BranchViewModel. Do I have to create two identical view models per view?

Comment: I mean on one View, I need ViewModel which is composed of ClientVM and BranchVM. The other view just needs ClientVM. Should I have two ClientVM per View?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how ASP.Net MVC works, but I would strive to have one VM per View. However you do not need duplication if you use composition. E.g. View1 consumes VM1 which is composed of ClientVM and BranchVM while V2 consumes ClientVM directly. Does that answer you question?

Comment: Yeah I think so. Ive been thinking about "to reuse" or " to duplicate per view" so i think reuse is way to go

Comment: But for your answer. We'll see others answer. I was looking specifically for asp mvc using entity framework

Comment: @Daskul DDD and CQRS don't care about implementation details like Mvc 5 or EF.  I can have the same design implemented with NancyFx and a micro-Orm. What plalx said is correct when doing design. If you're searching for a recipe using a specific tech, that's not how things work. Once you've understood the principles and the design, you can use whatever implementation you want, but at this point it's clear you need to grok the principles. Code is the last thing you should be doing.

Comment: Yes DDD doesnt care about implementation. But at the end of the day you have to implement the other layers. You cant say you're done with the Domain Model and its not your job to do the other layers, (or maybe yes?). Im interested how others implement them, like if they are using Domain Model directly on UI, throw in extra layer etc.. and their PROS and CONS depending on project size

Comment: @Daskul Well, you may very well say that depending on your situation ;) However if you're a full-stack developer then no you can't. Still, even if I'm alone on a project, I tend to act like if I was on a different team for every layers. When modeling the domain I do not think too much of other layers. I'd argue that there's never a good reason to query the domain model directly. Using this way of thinking will ensure that you will never feel the pain of stretching a single model for command and queries. The queries service will have to be designed against what the clients (UI) needs however.

Comment: Yeah Im also into that, I just feel introducing different layers gives a lot of extra work. Or maybe I just have a tight deadline ;)

Comment: How long is it really to write a DB query and a DTO?